# How to add onchange function inside php form input

Tags: java, php, onchange

This is my php form input

```
 <?php echo form_input(array('name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty", 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5'));  ?>
                    <button class="btn btn-success " onclick="update_cart('<?=$items['rowid'];?>')" >update</button>
```

Help me to add `onchange` function inside this

Comment: What framework are you using? Smarty? Why [Java] tag here?

Comment: Instead of Java, that tag must be javascript

Comment: I am using codeigniter. I am developing a shopping cart I need this functionality for my cart update section

Comment: @MayankPandeyz will you post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Please define the `onchange` key in the setter , to send in the function name itself then define your function in your javascript.

```
<?php echo form_input(array('name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'onchange'=> $items['onchange'], 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5'));  ?>
```

Comment: `onnchage` of value inside this field I need to goto some javascript function

Comment: @secondsight, yes . Do you have access to the javascript ?

Comment: `<?php echo form_input(array('name' => $items['rowid']."_qty",'id' => $items['rowid']."_qty", 'value' => $items['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'size' => '5'));  ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-success " onclick="update_cart('<?=$items['rowid'];?>')" >update</button>`  actually I have an update button with this field

Comment: @secondsight, could you share the function? so i can view the details. Because what you've showed me it's just an echo in PHP that `displays`